# how the splash view can be removed with a Bookopening like animation?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an Iphone application in which i am using an imageview to create a splash screen.and in the remove splash function i am removing that splash view and adding the navigation controllers view.Now i need to remove that splash view with a bookopening like animation like as did in the path application.can anybody help me to do that?

Comment: what type of animation is this bookopening ? Is it just like page view's page dragging animation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to look like a book cover opening, you could do an animation block, and just set the frame property to have a zero width:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,0,self.view.frame.size.height);

                     } 
                     completion:^ (BOOL finished){
                         [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                     }
     ];
```

Otherwise, just use the built-in page-turn animation as mentioned by rckoenes

Comment: thanks for the reply.now i changed the splash view to one view controller such as startupviewcontroller,i want to remove that view from the window with that animation and add the navigation view to the window,i dnt think it is possible with wat u posted above?